# Difficulty creating a functional Angular2 post

Tags: spring, http, post, angular

I'm trying to send a post request to another service (a Spring application), an authentication, but I'm having trouble constructing a functional Angular2 post request at all. I'm using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7xPwhwbcHE) for reference, which is pretty new, so I assume the information still valid. I'm also able to execute a get request with no problems.

Here's my post request:

```
export class LogIn {
    authUser: string;
    authPass: string;
    token: any;

    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    onSubmit() {
        var header = new Headers()
        var json = JSON.stringify({ user: this.authUser, password: this.authPass })
        var params2 = 'user=' + this.authUser + '&password=' + this.authPass
        var params = "json=" + json
        header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        this._http.post("http://validate.jsontest.com", params, {
            headers: header
        }).map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this.token = JSON.stringify(data),
                err => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('done')
            );
        console.log(this.token);
    }
}
```

The info is being correctly taken from a form, I tested it a couple of times to make sure. I am also using two different ways to build the json (params and params2). When I try to send the request to `http://validate.jsontest.com`, the console prints `undefined` where `this.token` should be. When I try to send the request to the Spring application, I get an error on that side:

`Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you need to use the GET method to do that:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
     user: this.authUser, password: this.authPass
});

var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('json', json);

this._http.get("http://validate.jsontest.com", {
  search: params
}).map(res => res.json());
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fAHPp49vFZJ8OuPC1043?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks, that works! In which situations must I use http.post?